# MySQL Invalid column count on special characters

Tags: mysql, csv, import, collation

I want to import a CSV file and I get the error `Invalid column count on line X`.  When I check the line X I find a special characters like `á  é  í  ó  ú`.  When I replace `á` with `a` the import continues until another row that contains another special character.

I want to import Geoip From Maxmind and the column is the column of the cities that contains that characters.

Comment: just a thought...hopefully it will help - could it be down to the chatset used in your database column/table? Try UTF8.

Comment: thanks for comment , it is called 'collation' and yeah , i tried UTF8 aswell ,still same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the solution is changing the `Character set of the file` of the `IMPORT` to `iso-8859-15`

This character set of the file by default is UTF-8, and it does not accept those characters. I am talking about about character set of the file not collation of the column

Comment: Treating any flavor of "latin" characters as if they were utf8 will lead to truncation of the field at the first such character.  Where did you get **-15**?  I ask because that is a character set that MySQL does not handle.  `á  é  í  ó  ú` are not a problem -- they are in latin1.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the hex for `á  é  í  ó  ú`.  If each is one byte, then you probably have "latin1" encoding.  If each is 2 bytes, the you probably have utf8.

In the import statement, state the CHARACTER SET you have.  MySQL will convert to the character set declared for the column you are importing into.

Those particular characters exist (with *different* encodings) in both latin1 and utf8.  But if you need *Eastern* European characters, say so; the task gets more involved.